# Applying for new credit card

Tags: credit-card

In the past (from 2014 to 2016) I went through some financial trouble and my 2 credit cards were closed sent to collection agencies since I fell behind my payments. I had 2 credit cards with a $1,500 credit limit each.

Since January 2017 everything has gotten better and I'm back on track with my finances. In March 2017 I paid the full balance on both of the credit cards and I also got a mortgage approved with my wife and closed my first house.

My question is. Will I be approved if I apply for a new credit card? Considering what happened before with the old credit cards?

Comment: So do you have any credit cards right now? You say both got closed, but you also say that you paid both off in full...

Comment: Why would you want to open that "can of worms" again?

Comment: Hey Michael, no I don't have a credit card right now. So I am trying to get a new credit card to start rebuilding my credit history. I paid both of the old credit cards in full through the collection agency.

Comment: This question can't really be answered, you have to just try. If your wife has good credit you likely won't have issue opening a joint account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael noted, a Secured card will seriously help. Putting any amount down on a card lowers the risk, as it increases the amount they can recover if you default. Some cards will give you a 3:1 or higher ratio on your security / downpayment on the card to your limit.

You could likely get an unsecured card, though not one with great terms / benefits.

I'd recommend finding a card that's meant for people with low or no credit.

These usually accept people with poor credit, but offer fairly few terms.

My first card was Capital One's 'Journey' card, which had a somewhat decent interest rate and no fee, along with a 1% cash back thing. It was aimed at students, so I got it with no background and a score at the time of about 630.

I think Credit Karma keeps details somewhere on your odds of getting approved for various cards, if you look at the cards through their site. The items shown there may be subject to bias, though, as Credit Karma gets a commission for referrals for cards.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the underwriter for the bank views your application. If you don't want to risk getting denied, then a secure credit card is the best way to go. You could apply for an unsecured one and if you get denied, you can ask for reconsideration and provide additional documentation to show that you are financially stable now. There's no straightforward answer on whether or not you will be approved. There are so many different caveats and such related to credit cards and how each bank plays differently.

Comment: Thank for your advice. I was thinking to try applying for a retail credit card since I heard they are easier to get approved. I had in mind the PC Mastercard. I am going to try applying for one and see if I can get approved for the unsecured Mastercard first.

Comment: @Sam Retail cards are notorious for being the worst in the industry. Highest interest rates, and 'deferred' interest instead of 'no' interest offers as intro period benefits (It's only 0% if you pay off within 6 months, otherwise you get charged interest from day 1, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You have two big issues in your situation:

- your less than perfect credit history. Which you have overcome by paying back the debt, and getting a mortgage with your spouse.
- your recent new loan. The card issuer may not be willing to offer a credit card just a few months after getting the mortgage. In your case you could, as others have suggested, apply for a secured card.